# Need help with PL SQL Query [Execute Immediate]

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this query

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE  ' || dest || ' SET COUNTRY_CODE = :v1 WHERE col_id = :v2 returning rowid into :out' 
          USING l_vc_CountryCode, l_vc_ColId
          returning into l_vc_rowid;
```

the l_vc_rowid is defined as varchar2(10);

I am trying to google, but couldn't find the problem.

Comment: What is the problem with your query, are you getting an error message? which one?

Comment: a little digging into the issue made me realize that the error is ***unsupported feature with RETURNING***. All i want to know if the given value has been updated or not, I don't want to use a separate select statement. Any ideas?

Comment: Would you mind rephrasing your question title so it is less generic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sql%rowcount` to determine how many rows were affected by the update.

With a working PL/SQL function:

```
create table tq84_update_test (
  country_code number,
  col_id       varchar2(10)
);


create or replace 
function tq84_update_func (dest         in varchar2, 
                           col_id       in varchar2,
                           country_code in number  
                           )
return varchar2
as
begin

  execute immediate 
 'update ' || dest || ' set country_code = :v1 ' ||
 'where col_id = :v2' 
  using country_code, col_id;

  return sql%rowcount || ' rows updated';
end tq84_update_func;
/


insert into tq84_update_test values (4,'Italy');

exec dbms_output.put_line(tq84_update_func('tq84_update_test', 'foo', 2));

exec dbms_output.put_line(tq84_update_func('tq84_update_test', 'Italy', 9));

select * from tq84_update_test;
```

Comment: could you give me a written example? Thanks,